# How to use order by command for month in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select
    Round(Sum(Totalamount) / Sum(totalweight), 2) as AVGRATE
    , DATENAME(MONTH, LIFTINGDATE) as [Month]
from k_LiftingEntryRecords 
where liftingdate BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND '2013-07-30 00:00:00.000'
group by DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE)
order by DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE)
```

Iam getting May, June, July, April. I need April, May.....

Comment: order by MONTH(LIFTINGDATE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another MONTH(LIFTINGDATE) column in select list and group by list

```
SELECT  
 Round(Sum(Totalamount)/Sum(totalweight),2)as AVGRATE
,DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE) 
,MONTH(LIFTINGDATE)
as [Month] from k_LiftingEntryRecords 
where (liftingdate BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND '2013-07-30 00:00:00.000')
group by DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE),MONTH(LIFTINGDATE)
order by MONTH(LIFTINGDATE)
```

If you need same column list then

```
SELECT AVGRATE,Month_Name FROM
(
    SELECT  
     Round(Sum(Totalamount)/Sum(totalweight),2)as AVGRATE
    ,DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE) AS Month_Name 
    ,MONTH(LIFTINGDATE) MonthNum
    as [Month] from k_LiftingEntryRecords 
    where (liftingdate BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND '2013-07-30 00:00:00.000')
    group by DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE),MONTH(LIFTINGDATE)
) T
ORDER BY MonthNum
```

Comment: ... order by MONTH(LIFTINGDATE)

Answer (score 1):

try-:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, LIFTINGDATE) as [Month]
FROM (
    SELECT '2005-01-03 00:00:00.000' AS LIFTINGDATE
    UNION ALL SELECT '2005-07-06 00:00:00.000'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2005-03-03 00:00:00.000'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2005-06-05 00:00:00.000'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2005-04-02 00:00:00.000'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2005-05-04 00:00:00.000'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2005-02-16 00:00:00.000'
) AS X
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, LIFTINGDATE), MONTH(LIFTINGDATE)
ORDER BY [Month]
```

Comment: ... or just `order by LIFTINGDATE`, and consider that you must add "new" columns into `group by` statement

Comment: If I add new columns in group by then my output may differ

Comment: `LIFTINGDATE` is the same column in `order by` and `group by`

Comment: since month name is as unique as month number, output will be always the same

Answer (score -1):

Try below..

```
select  Round(Sum(Totalamount)/Sum(totalweight),2)as AVGRATE
,DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE) as [Month] 
from k_LiftingEntryRecords 
where (liftingdate BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND '2013-07-30 00:00:00.000')
group by DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE) 
order by Month
```

Comment: this will produce the same problem with the OPs original question